# how to get access token in word document 365 in desktop view

Tags: angular, office-js, office-addins

manifast.xml

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</Id>
      <Resource>api://localhost:4200/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>Files.ReadWrite.All</Scope>
        <Scope>Sites.ReadWrite.All</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
        <Scope>openid</Scope>
      </Scopes>
    </WebApplicationInfo>
```

code for access token in office js

```
 let bootstrapToken = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({
        allowSignInPrompt: true,
        allowConsentPrompt: true,
        forMSGraphAccess: false,
      });
```

[image]
above error display when get access token.

get access token